# bangular: Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?

Tags: gulp-sass, libsass

I'm getting this error while doing `gulp build` task after installing "bangular" project (`yo bangular`).

> Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?

Answer (score 0):

seems like this is because of the latest node, python versions

To resolve this:
    I have pointed the environment variable `PYTHON` to python27 binary

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass@latest

npm uninstall gulp-sass
npm install gulp-sass@latest
```

also, deleted global node-gyp module (from `/nodejs/node_modules/npm/node_modules/` dir) and re-installed (`npm install -g node-gyp@latest`).